# Swift : 3.1 UILabel text not updating in timer (Call every second)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have created one timer object and set #selector method, In #selector method my label update every time that display timer count down value, but when I push or pop another view controller and come back to timer view controller my label not updating timer count down value

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   if timer == nil {
    self.startTimer()
   }
}

func startTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

func update()  {

    count += 1
    if(count > 0){

        let ti = NSInteger(count)
        let strSeconds = ti % 60
        let strMinutes = (ti / 60) % 60
        let strHours = (ti / 3600)

        print("\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)")
        self.lblTimer.text = String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",strHours,strMinutes,strSeconds)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post your code that creates the timer, as well as the function that the timer calls. My guess is that you're creating your timer in viewDidLoad, which only gets called once in the lifetime of your view controller. If you stop your timer, push another view controller on top, then pop, viewDidLoad won't be called again.

Comment: Also, make sure you invalidate/nullify your timer at some point in the lifecycle prior to removing your view controller from the stack (not in `deinit`) otherwise you'll create a memory leak.

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same?
I face same issue when pop view controller and get back to the screen

Answer (score -1):

When you use the selector try `self.update()` to actually call the function. May also put a print statement to check that your variable is indeed incrementing.

Comment: Baaulos also working properly ,but my issue i'm going popviewcontoller and agin push viewcontroller in print("\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)") working but  UILabel text not updating